# Discord bot returning permission errors

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

My Discord bot keeps returning these errors and I'm not sure how to deal with them since I'm still very new to this whole coding thing.

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
at RequestHandler.execute (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:170:25)
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:15) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 39)
```

It seems to happen whenever someone attempts to use a command in a Discord channel where my bot cannot send messages.

This is the code I use for a command:

```
client.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.author.bot || message.content.trim() == "") return;
  if (message.content.toLowerCase().trim() == "cat") {
    const { file } = await fetch("https://aws.random.cat/meow").then(response =>
      response.json()
    );
    return message.channel.send(new $().setColor("RANDOM").setTitle("Your Cat").setImage(file).setFooter('Powered by Catastic'));
  }
});
```

I hope ya'll can help me!

Comment: Try entering on this website https://discordapi.com/permissions.html#8 set your bot client ID and enter on the address, this way you set Administrator permissions to your bot

Answer (score 0):

Your bot doesn't have permissions to send a message to the channel the user have written in. Try giving the "Send Messages" permission in that channel using the Permissions menu.

Comment: I did figure that out but the problem is that my bot is public and it's currently in 99 servers. I cannot give my bot permissions in servers I'm not a member of. 
Is there something I can do to disable those error messages?